# Retrieving VHD information from Hyper-V without using PowerShell or WMI

Tags: hyper-v

Is there any way to find some informations relating to virtual disks in Hyper-V without calling PowerShell or WMI commands? Maybe something like xml files for virtual disks (like the snapshot xml files)?

In fact I was wondering to get information related to virtual disks without asking powershell or HyperV Manager like: storageName that hosts the VirtualDisk, its order in the VM attached with etc...

Comment: What specific information are you looking for? Also, when you ask a question, please try to stick to the point a bit more. It might be worthwhile for you to read the [faq] and [ask]. This isn't a discussion area like a typical forum :) I've edited your question to be less chatty and more to-the-point. This will make it easier for you to get an actual answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: if you don't see the xml files where the snapshot files are then you are using the default location which is c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\hyper-v

Comment: Vote to close. What information you look for?

Comment: Information needed: storageName that hosts the VirtualDisk,

Comment: also why not use powershell\wmi?

Comment: In fact , I am using an api for requests hyperv but using powershell or wmi the response seems so slow...looking for files containing this information seems better for this case.

Comment: I was trying during 3 days to find a way to retrieve such information (which is simple to find with vmware or xen)...powershell dosent appear so powerfull and unfortunately it seems so complicated...it s better to switch to other thing more powerfull and simple....thank you for help :-)

Comment: if powershell is so bad why is vmware touting powershell as the script language of choice for their own platform.

Comment: PowerShell is *the* way of the future for MS products. For example, PowerShell is the **only** command-line interface to Exchange 2010 and SQL Server 2012. Every single GUI action in those apps really just calls PowerShell commands underneath. There's no excuse to put off learning PowerShell any more.

Answer (score 2):

The only interface to get this from a Hyper-V host is through WMI.  The Powershell objects just use WMI internally.

And while you may find what you're looking for by trying to interpret the XML representations of a VM that are the VM configuration files, their format is internal to Hyper-V, and thus is may change from release to release.